# Getting selector over tabs to resize and move as required?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code as below, which gives me a number of tabs. I'm having a problem with selector where if you click on the bottom line selector won't move down.

[image]

Also if resize it more the selector gets even worse. Is there a way to get Selector to work properly in a way that it would fill the wrapper container or just match the text?

[image]

[image]

```
<style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
    @import url('https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css');

    body {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }

    .wrapper {
        /*
        text-align: center;
        */
        margin: 50px auto;
    }

    .tabs {
        margin-top: 50px;
        font-size: 15px;
        padding: 0px;
        list-style: none;
        background: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
               /*
        display: inline-block;
 */
        border-radius: 50px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .tabs a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #777;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        transition-duration: 0.6s;
    }

    .tabs a.active {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .tabs a i {
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

    .tabs .selector {
        height: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        z-index: 1;
        border-radius: 50px;
        transition-duration: 0.6s;
        transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
        background: #05abe0;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #05abe0 0%, #8200f4 100%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #05abe0 0%, #8200f4 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(45deg, #05abe0 0%, #8200f4 100%);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#05abe0', endColorstr='#8200f4', GradientType=1);
    }


    .tabs-content {
        display: none;
    }

    .tabs-content.active {
        display: block;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="tabs">
        <div class="selector"></div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="active" data-id="1"><i class="fas fa-burn"></i>Avengers</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="2"><i class="fas fa-bomb"></i>Guardians of The Galaxy</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="3"><i class="fas fa-bolt"></i>Thor</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="4"><i class="fab fa-superpowers"></i>Black Panther</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="4"><i class="fab fa-superpowers"></i>Black Panther</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="4"><i class="fab fa-superpowers"></i>Black Panther</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="4"><i class="fab fa-superpowers"></i>Black Panther</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="4"><i class="fab fa-superpowers"></i>Black Panther</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="4"><i class="fab fa-superpowers"></i>Black Panther</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="4"><i class="fab fa-superpowers"></i>Black Panther</a>

    </nav>
</div>

<div class="tabs-content active" id="content1">
    <p>
        Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet beef venison beef ribs kielbasa. Sausage pig leberkas, t-bone sirloin shoulder
        bresaola. Frankfurter rump porchetta ham. Pork belly prosciutto brisket meatloaf short ribs.
    </p>
    <p>
        Brisket meatball turkey short loin boudin leberkas meatloaf chuck andouille pork loin pastrami spare ribs
        pancetta rump. Frankfurter corned beef beef tenderloin short loin meatloaf swine ground round venison.
    </p>
</div>

<div class="tabs-content" id="content2">
    <p>
        Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet landjaeger sausage brisket, jerky drumstick fatback boudin ball tip turducken.
        Pork
        belly meatball t-bone bresaola tail filet mignon kevin turkey ribeye shank flank doner cow kielbasa shankle.
        Pig
        swine chicken hamburger, tenderloin turkey rump ball tip sirloin frankfurter meatloaf boudin brisket ham
        hock.
        Hamburger venison brisket tri-tip andouille pork belly ball tip short ribs biltong meatball chuck. Pork chop
        ribeye tail short ribs, beef hamburger meatball kielbasa rump corned beef porchetta landjaeger flank. Doner
        rump
        frankfurter meatball meatloaf, cow kevin pork pork loin venison fatback spare ribs salami beef ribs.
    </p>
    <p>
        Jerky jowl pork chop tongue, kielbasa shank venison. Capicola shank pig ribeye leberkas filet mignon brisket
        beef kevin tenderloin porchetta. Capicola fatback venison shank kielbasa, drumstick ribeye landjaeger beef
        kevin
        tail meatball pastrami prosciutto pancetta. Tail kevin spare ribs ground round ham ham hock brisket
        shoulder.
        Corned beef tri-tip leberkas flank sausage ham hock filet mignon beef ribs pancetta turkey.
    </p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var tabs = $('.tabs');
    var items = $('.tabs').find('a').length;
    var selector = $(".tabs").find(".selector");
    var activeItem = tabs.find('.active');
    var activeWidth = activeItem.innerWidth();
    var activeHeight = activeItem.innerHeight();

    $(".selector").css({
        "left": activeItem.position.left + "px",
        "right": activeItem.position.right + "px",
        "width": activeWidth + "px",
        "height": activeHeight + "px"
    });

    $(".tabs").on("click", "a", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.tabs a').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var activeWidth = $(this).innerWidth();
        var itemPos = $(this).position();
        $(".selector").css({
            "left": itemPos.left + "px",
            "width": activeWidth + "px"
        });

        // Hide all tabs
        $('.tabs-content').hide();

        // Get id of link clicked
        var id = $(this).data("id");

        // Show current tab
        $('#content' + id).show();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using the "selector" div could you not just apply the style to the active "a" tag?

**Edit**

Okay I see what you are trying to do with regards to the selector animating to the clicked item.

Add "right" and "bottom" to the .selector CSS as follows:

```
.tabs .selector {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition-duration: 0.6s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
    background: #05abe0;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #05abe0 0%, #8200f4 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #05abe0 0%, #8200f4 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #05abe0 0%, #8200f4 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#05abe0', endColorstr='#8200f4', GradientType=1);
}
```

And add "top" position in the following part of the code:

```
 $(".tabs").on("click", "a", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.tabs a').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var activeWidth = $(this).innerWidth();
        var itemPos = $(this).position();
        $(".selector").css({
            "left": itemPos.left + "px",
             "top": itemPos.top + "px",
            "width": activeWidth + "px"
        });
```

**Edit 2**

To set all elements to the be the same width you could use:

```
  var maxWidth = 0;
var $element;
$(".tabs a").each(function(){
   $element = $(this);
   if($element.width() > maxWidth){
     maxWidth = $element.width();
   }

});

  $(".tabs a").each(function(){
   $(this).width(maxWidth);

});
```

**Edit 3**

This is an example of the code as discussed in the comments:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="tabs">
        <div class="selector"></div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="active" data-id="1"><i class="fas fa-burn"></i>Avengers</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="2"><i class="fas fa-bomb"></i>Guardians of The Galaxy</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="3"><i class="fas fa-bolt"></i>Thor</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="4"><i class="fab fa-superpowers"></i>Black Panther</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="5"><i class="fab fa-superpowers"></i>Black Panther</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="6"><i class="fab fa-superpowers"></i>Black Panther</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="7"><i class="fab fa-superpowers"></i>Black Panther</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="8"><i class="fab fa-superpowers"></i>Black Panther</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="9"><i class="fab fa-superpowers"></i>Black Panther</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="10"><i class="fab fa-superpowers"></i>Black Panther</a>

    </nav>
</div>

<div class="tabs-content active" id="content1">
    <p>
        Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet beef venison beef ribs kielbasa. Sausage pig leberkas, t-bone sirloin shoulder
        bresaola. Frankfurter rump porchetta ham. Pork belly prosciutto brisket meatloaf short ribs.
    </p>
    <p>
        Brisket meatball turkey short loin boudin leberkas meatloaf chuck andouille pork loin pastrami spare ribs
        pancetta rump. Frankfurter corned beef beef tenderloin short loin meatloaf swine ground round venison.
    </p>
</div>

<div class="tabs-content" id="content2">
    <p>
        Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet landjaeger sausage brisket, jerky drumstick fatback boudin ball tip turducken.
        Pork
        belly meatball t-bone bresaola tail filet mignon kevin turkey ribeye shank flank doner cow kielbasa shankle.
        Pig
        swine chicken hamburger, tenderloin turkey rump ball tip sirloin frankfurter meatloaf boudin brisket ham
        hock.
        Hamburger venison brisket tri-tip andouille pork belly ball tip short ribs biltong meatball chuck. Pork chop
        ribeye tail short ribs, beef hamburger meatball kielbasa rump corned beef porchetta landjaeger flank. Doner
        rump
        frankfurter meatball meatloaf, cow kevin pork pork loin venison fatback spare ribs salami beef ribs.
    </p>
    <p>
        Jerky jowl pork chop tongue, kielbasa shank venison. Capicola shank pig ribeye leberkas filet mignon brisket
        beef kevin tenderloin porchetta. Capicola fatback venison shank kielbasa, drumstick ribeye landjaeger beef
        kevin
        tail meatball pastrami prosciutto pancetta. Tail kevin spare ribs ground round ham ham hock brisket
        shoulder.
        Corned beef tri-tip leberkas flank sausage ham hock filet mignon beef ribs pancetta turkey.
    </p>
</div>


<script>

var maxWidth = 0;
var $element;
$(".tabs a").each(function(){
   $element = $(this);
   if($element.width() > maxWidth){
     maxWidth = $element.width();
   }
});

$(window).on('resize', function(){
            $(".selector").hide();
      var activeItem = $(".tabs a[class*='active']");
      var id = activeItem.data("id");
      setSelectorPosition(id);
});

$(".tabs a").each(function(){
   $(this).width(maxWidth);

});

  // Set first active link
  setSelectorPosition(1);



    $(".tabs").on("click", "a", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.tabs a').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass('active');

        // Get id of link clicked
        var id = $(this).data("id");

        // Set selector position
        setSelectorPosition(id);

        // Hide all tabs
        $('.tabs-content').hide();

        // Show current tab
        $('#content' + id).show();
    });

    function setSelectorPosition(id) {          
            var activeItem = $(".tabs").find("[data-id='" + id + "']"); 
        var activeWidth = activeItem.innerWidth();
        var itemPos = activeItem.position();
        $(".selector").css({
            "left": itemPos.left + "px",
             "top": itemPos.top + "px",
            "width": activeItem.innerWidth() + "px",
            "height": activeItem.innerHeight() + "px"
        });
        $(".selector").show();
    }

</script>

<style>

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
    @import url('https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css');

    body {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }

    .wrapper {

        text-align: center;

        margin: 50px auto;
    }

    .tabs {
        margin-top: 50px;
        font-size: 15px;
        list-style: none;
        background: #fff;
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); 
        display: inline-block;

        border-radius: 50px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .tabs a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #777;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        transition-duration: 0.6s;
    }

    .tabs a.active {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .tabs a i {
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

    .tabs .selector {
        display:none;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        right:0px;
        bottom:0px;
        z-index: 1;
        border-radius: 50px;
        transition-duration: 0.6s;
        transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
        background: #05abe0;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #05abe0 0%, #8200f4 100%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #05abe0 0%, #8200f4 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(45deg, #05abe0 0%, #8200f4 100%);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#05abe0', endColorstr='#8200f4', GradientType=1);
    }


    .tabs-content {
        display: none;
    }

    .tabs-content.active {
        display: block;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: I probably could. I'm just not really experienced in CSS/JS/HTML so I don't really know what I am doing.

Comment: It does work, but I'm having 2 more issues with it. When I uncomment text-align in wrapper it stops working correctly. And it doesn't really look nice when switching thru other items (for one it goes outbound of wrapper but also generally it does look unpleasant. Is there way to maybe size text to be sized based on longest txt? and maybe center it? That would make it a bit more pleasant?

Comment: I have added an example for making all elements the same width.

Comment: You might also want to add $(window).on('resize', function(){
      ** Set selector position here **
}); so that if the browser window is resized it sets the selector position correctly.

Comment: Ye it seems that selector is placed wrong if i change wrapper to `.wrapper { text-align: center;margin: 50px auto;  }`

Comment: Do you mean just the initial selector? The rest seems to be working fine as per this example: https://jsfiddle.net/1rgsj96L/

Comment: Yes, initial one. And as you noticed it goes out of bounds. Not sure if it can fill borders properly?

Comment: Take a look at the updated fiddle here which sets the position of the initial item: https://jsfiddle.net/4asdLomn/

Comment: I have updated again to resolve the issue with the initial load so that it is hidden by default and then shown after it is set for the first time: https://jsfiddle.net/4asdLomn/2/

Comment: Yep, seems to work properly. Another problem out of my list. 2 more to go. Resize problem you mentioned already and going out of bounds for wrapper? Would it be possible to fit it a bit more closely? And match the borders? Or that's too much work and hard to do ?

Comment: See update with the resize code added. Not sure what you mean about going out of bounds, how can this be replicated? Is this in a particular browser, I am testing in Google Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/4asdLomn/3/

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/X4OZiit the selector goes outside of the wrapper. I would like it to be within borders.

Comment: And i guess the hardest part here would be having it actually fill the borders (in terms the selector should match the border of the wrapper when it's on the top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right and right  and left. If you know what I mean? But I guess that's some serious work on CSS part.

Comment: Yes I think the problem is that because the curve of the border doesn't match the curve of the selector due to the size of the tabs div that will be quite difficult, and where the selector is absolute positioned it doesn't know not to go outside of the containing div.

Comment: Right. Ok, could you update your answer with final data so it's useful for everyone?

Comment: I've updated my answer, no worries, hope I have helped :-)

Comment: One more thing, if I would like to have selector of even size per each row? Is that possible/easy? Assuming I would stop using round corners it would be nicer looking I guess? Depending on amount of elements per row it can be different. Like first row has 5-7 elements and bottom one has 3 or 1. The selector for the bottom one would need to fill the whole page..

Comment: Or better yet, have an even number per each row if possible.

Comment: I think the issue with it not working and having to set all links to be the same width is due to the scrollbar showing and not showing when selected links that didn't have any tab content which therefore made the "tabs" div slightly wider or narrower. I have added tab content for all the items and removed the "same width for all links" code and think it works a lot better: https://jsfiddle.net/sgt045ab/

Comment: It does look better, but it does fail if it's just 1 row  (the selector is not properly aligned).

Comment: Also is there a way setSelectorPosition(1); to fix it so 1 isn't hardcoded? As it taking active tab (really active) when starting? I have code that autogenerates ID's and id isn't called 1,2,3 and so on.

Comment: `var activeItem = $(".tabs a[class*='active']");
    var id = activeItem.data("id");
    setSelectorPosition(id); ` seems to do the trick